# Get Column height and width and update on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="columna1"> CONTENT1 </div>
<div class="columna2"> CONTENT2 </div>
```

And this javascript:

```
column1_height = $('#columna1').height();
column1_width = $('#columna1').width();
column2_height = $('#columna2').height();
column2_width = $('#columna2').width();
```

But when I resize the screen the values does not update.

Thanks

Comment: put the code in `onresize` event handler

Comment: what's the diference with Marcos Aguayo's answer? which is better? I'm new in programming

Comment: "what's the diference", i don't see any difference he's also used the `onresize` event

Comment: He used "resize" instead of "onresize" is the same?

Comment: in `jquery`  ,you can omit `on`

Comment: Yes, it's the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('ready', initFunction);
$(window).on('resize', getSizes);

var column1_height = 0;
var column1_width = 0;
var column2_height = 0;
var column2_width = 0;

function initFunction(){
    getSizes();
}

function getSizes(){
    column1_height = $('#columna1').height();
    column1_width = $('#columna1').width();
    column2_height = $('#columna2').height();
    column2_width = $('#columna2').width();

    console.log("Column 1: (Height: " +column1_height+ ") - (Width: " +column1_width+ ")");
    console.log("Column 2: (Height: " +column2_height+ ") - (Width: " +column2_width+ ")");
}
```

This should work